# The Image created from a snapshot does not launch the instance properly

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I was working on the mirroring of the instance. I followed these steps:

1. create an image(AMI) of the instance you would like to mirror
2. Launch an instance out of the image
3. ssh into the new instance and launch the processes

The new instance is running properly.

I also tried the another method.:

1. Create a snapshot of an instance
2. Create an image from snapshot
3. Try and launch the instance from the image.

But somehow the server is not getting set up properly in the second method and it fails the status checks built in Amazon console. I need to figure out the reason as it may be critical at some point to be able to launch a server from the snapshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the AMI from the snapshot, make sure you select the same Architecture, Kernel ID, RAM Disk ID (if applicable) and Root Device Name that is used by the instance from which the snapshot was taken.

Leaving values as "Use Default" will likely cause problems.

[image: AWS Console Create Image Dialog]

Comment: This was the problem.